# How to make second request on NSMutableURLRequest?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am trying to make a connection with session by using NSMutableURLRequest. I am starting the first request I receive data from it. But I can't make the second request. How can I make the second request by using the same cookie?

Update source code:

```
NSHTTPURLResponse   * response;
NSError             * error;
NSMutableURLRequest * request;
request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://loginsite"]
                                        cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                    timeoutInterval:60];
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"userid=%@&pass=%@",self.userName.text, self.password.text];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];


self.urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[self.urlConnection start];
```

it makes the first request but how can I make the second one?

Comment: Can you provide some code as to what is happening and what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are an HTTP thingy so I assume we are talking about that.
When the 1. request succeeds you get a NSURLResponse which is an HTTPURLResponse with headers that can be resolved to cookies:

```
NSArray *cookies = [NSHTTPCookie cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields:headers forURL:[self url]]];
```

those cookies can then be used with the 2. request...

```
NSDictionary * headers = [NSHTTPCookie requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies:cookies];
[request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];
```